# How to debug servlet in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, debugging, tomcat, servlets

i am using `out.print("bug");` at various points in my servlet but the output is not received on the console.
There are no log files either, double clicking on server name in servers tab shows debug logging is not supported in this version of tomcat.
What can i do now to debug my servlet ?

Comment: Aren't you asking the wrong question? Don't you rather want to find out where exactly the `out` prints to, so you can advance?

Comment: i would greatly appreciate that knowledge, thank you.

Comment: Telling the exact Eclipse and Tomcat versions would help to start.

Comment: Eclipse indigo with Tomcat v7.0

Comment: Which Eclipse Indigo exactly? Is it the stock Eclipse for Java EE? Or did you originally had Eclipse for Java SE and did you manually install WTP plugins and so on? In its default trim, Eclipse for Java EE has already the right Tomcat server plugins builtin and any `System.out.println()` calls should normally end up in *Console*. Nonetheless, Indigo is pretty old. Upgrading/replacing it wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Yes, will switch to mars after this project, just somehow i can get past this problem.

Comment: Just to exclude an ambiguity, the `out` in your question is from `System.out`, right? Because, inside a JSP file, that would be `response.getOutputStream()` which thus ends up in HTTP response and gets displayed in webbrowser instead (but you would be really tired  if you did not immediately see that ;) )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109387/discussion-between-nimit-johri-and-balusc).

Comment: Sorry, I don't use the chat feature. Just continue here.

Comment: ok, i am using `out.print("bug");` exactly like this, although i have also tried `System.out.println("");`, anyhow i just want my message to be printed anywhere as i only want to use it for debugging my servlet.

Comment: Servlets do not support `out` property. So this adds another red herring to your question: what class exactly is it now? Well, as the `System.out.println()` also does not work, can you assure that you have performed a full clean/rebuild/redeploy/restart after you edited the source code? Can you assure that the produced WAR file contains the correct version of the compiled class file? (hint: more than often starters somehow accidentally disable *Project > Build Automatically* option in Eclipse).

Comment: The Build Automatically option is checked.
If both `out` & `SOP` does not work then what option do i have to debug parts of the code of my servlet ?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint within the JSP file and debugging it in Tomcat, using the **Debug on Server** action off the **Debug** menu?  http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftdbgjsp.html

Comment: I can understand why `System.out` wouldn't show anything in console, but if `out` already doesn't show anything in HTTP response, then you've an entirely different problem. As to putting breakpoints in JSP, sorry I never write Java code in a JSP file, only in a Java file (e.g. a Servlet class). I only write JSP code in a JSP file.